# Flutter HttpServer cannot access from other computers on the LAN network

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to implement feature that enables send data to the Flutter android app through http server. For example I want to make vibration on the app when my node.js app tasks running on Windows ends.

Here example from [Write HTTP clients & servers | Dart](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver) and this works on localhost:8080 on the android. But does not work on LAN network, e.g. from this Windows machine thought the android LAN IP address "http://192.168.0.193:8080/". I did google and searched Stack overflow, and found I needed `--web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0` when run Flutter, but still this doesn't work, this shows me `192.168.0.193 refused to connect.` The android IP is confirmed through `settings > wifi > wifi preference > advanced > IP addresses` and I'm sure the IP itself is correct.

So, I have no idea why I cannot connect to the app through the local IP address. Greatly appreciate your help, thanks.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future main() async {

  var server = await HttpServer.bind(
    InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4,
    8080,
  );

  print('Listening on ${server.address.toString()}:${server.port} ');


  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
    request.response.write('Hello, world!');  
    await request.response.close();
  }

}
```

```
flutter run -d F5122 --web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using InternetAddress.anyIPv4 instead of InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4 solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this:

```
  var server = await HttpServer.bind(
    InternetAddress("192.168.1.X"),
    8080,
  );
```

Replace the value X with the number of your server computer

This way you can access from another computer.